# como definir uma resolução minima

Tags: html, css

Bom estou montando um sisteminha em php para controle de caixa. Será um sistema voltado apenas para computadores, ou seja não será responsável.

Criei o menu, as informações dos caixas e etc...

Esta tudo 100%, porém notei que em alguns computadores com resolução baixa ou ate mesmo se eu diminuir a janela do meu browser, algumas div do sistema apresentam quebre de linha. Tem alguma forma de evitar isso, configurar uma resolução mínima e quando ele for atingida ciar uma barra de rolagem ao invés de quebras de linhas?

O site do facebook faz isso, por mais que vc diminua o browser  ele não muda as posições dos objetos e cria uma barra de rolagem.

Comment: Crie uma div container(que envolverá todo o conteúdo), e defina um width: 1000px ou o tamanho fixo que você queira que ela fique.

Comment: então eu queria esta div com with 100% porem o mínimo seria with:800px. Da para fazer isso? usando jQuery sei la hahaha

Comment: Então ficaria width:100% e min-width:800px;

Comment: Jquery kkkk ainda não é pra tanto kk

Comment: hahahhaha vlw vou testar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

No seu css, na tag body defina:

```
body {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```